# Aspnet Boilerplate / Aspnet Zero slow (IoC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, aspnetboilerplate

I use the aspnetboilerplate/aspnetzero template for my Multi-Tenant SaaS application with Multi-Database.
This uses CastleWindsor as DI Framework.

I experience very bad performance and I tracked it down with dotTrace - it says that Castle.MicroKernel is the most active code.

My requests take about 5-6 seconds and most of the time passes before it even hits the controller. (while debugging) 
I think that resolving all services/controllers is slow. I changed some dependencies (App-Services) from Transient to PerWebRequestLifetime but it didn't affect performance.

Does anyone know, how I can get better performance?

In my Views (_Layout file) I call several different Childactions, that are on Layoutcontroller, this Controller gets following Services injected:

```
     public LayoutController(
        IPerSessionCache sessionCache,
        IUserNavigationManager userNavigationManager,
        IMultiTenancyConfig multiTenancyConfig,
        ILanguageManager languageManager,
        ITenancyNameFinder tenancyNameFinder,
        TenantManager tenantManager,
        IUserLinkAppService userLinkAppService,
        UserManager userManager)
```

Actions are

```
[ChildActionOnly]
    public PartialViewResult AppHeader()
    {
        var headerModel = new Areas.Mpa.Models.Layout.HeaderViewModel
        {
            LoginInformations = AsyncHelper.RunSync(_sessionCache.GetCurrentLoginInformationsAsync),
            Languages = _languageManager.GetLanguages(),
            CurrentLanguage = _languageManager.CurrentLanguage,
            IsMultiTenancyEnabled = _multiTenancyConfig.IsEnabled,
            IsImpersonatedLogin = AbpSession.ImpersonatorUserId.HasValue,
            HasLinkedAccounts = AsyncHelper.RunSync(_userLinkAppService.HasLinkedAccounts)
        };

        return PartialView("~/Views/Layout/_AppHeader.cshtml", headerModel);
    }

[ChildActionOnly]
    public PartialViewResult AppNavbar(string currentPageName = "")
    {
        var sidebarModel = new Areas.Mpa.Models.Layout.NavbarViewModel
        {        
            Menu = AsyncHelper.RunSync(() => _userNavigationManager.GetMenuAsync(MeNavigationProvider.MenuName, AbpSession.ToUserIdentifier())),
            CurrentPageName = currentPageName
        };

        return PartialView("_AppNavbar", sidebarModel);
    }
```

and similar ones...But I checked the performance with an empty Layout File but my requests still take way too long

Comment: Are you injecting any service in your `.cshtml` pages? Is it only one controller? Show relevant code.

Comment: In the ViewPageBase I Resolve IAbpSession (but I think this was out of the box of aspnetzero when we generated the project)
And I have a HtmlHelperExtension LocalizedDisplayNameFor that resolves
a LocationManager

var localizationManager = IocManager.Instance.Resolve<ILocalizationManager>();

But I release it at the end of the method

Comment: I removed them, it might is a bit faster now, but this could be coincidence too.
DotTrace looks like this:
https://i.imgur.com/56LFU70.png
 Could it be a problem, to call several Child-Actions in the Layout cshtml? Does this always resolve a new LayoutController?

Comment: Make sure your [injection constructors are fast](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/). You are probably doing some kind of I/O during object graph construction.

Comment: have you used any interceptor? intercepting app services or controllers may misbehave

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to Stevens comment:

> Make sure your injection constructors are fast. You are probably doing some kind of I/O during object graph construction.

I actually figured out, that this was the problem. One of our Services did I/O in the constructor - which is very slow and results in bad performance of the IoC-Container instantiating it.

Answer (score 6):

**ASP.NET Boilerplate performance benchmark results**

We created 2 identical simple application: One with ABP (https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate-samples/tree/master/TestProjects/AbpPerformanceTestApp)

and other without ABP (https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate-samples/tree/master/TestProjects/StandartTestApp)

Used Frameworks

- ASP.NET Core 1.x
- EF Core 1.x

**Test Tool**

We used jMeter for tests.

**Test Results**

Without ABP

[image: Without ABP]

**With ABP**

[image: With ABP]

As seen in the statistics, ABP has added average 5ms overhead on top of a default asp.net code. Since this overhead is CPU usage, throughput is average 5% different.

We disabled Logging and Transaction of ABP for a better comparison (Logging especially effects performance since it uses I/O). Other aspects, filters and features are enabled as by default.